# Limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{x}-1}{x^{2}}$ and problems

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

The problem is straight forward enough, but I'm stuck.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x^2}$$

Since I get $0 / 0$ I can use L'Hopital's rule, but after the first differentiation I get $1/0$.  So, I can't continue with using that rule.  What approach next?

Comment: Vertical asymptote at $x=0$.  The limit does not exist.

Comment: @AndrewChin Sorry my bad I though $x$ approaches $1$. Deleted my comment!

Comment: @AndrewChin  I see the vertical asymptote at $x=0$, but if the power of $x$ is even can't there be a limit?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac1{x^2}$ does not exist either.  You can say that for $f(x)=\frac1{x^2}$, as $x\to 0$, $f(x)\to\infty$, which describes the end behaviour of the function, but even so, the limit does not exist.

Comment: I like your answer 1.  But in my class, the teacher expects me to answer the limit as x goes to zero of $1/x^2$ to be the end behavior, which is infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fun, unconventional way to think about it.  If we suppose the limit exists, we have
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x^2}&=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}\cdot\frac1x\\
&=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac1x\\
&=1\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac1x
\end{align}

But we know that for $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac1x$, the limit does not exist.  Curious.

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly identified that you can apply L'Hopital's rule once to find

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x}{2x}$$

Next consider the left-hand limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}} \frac{e^x}{2x}=\frac{1}{0^{-}}=-\infty$$

and the right-hand limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{e^x}{2x}=\frac{1}{0^{+}}=\infty$$
so that

$$-\infty=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}} \frac{e^x}{2x}\neq \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{e^x}{2x}=\infty$$

What can you now conclude about the limit as $x\to 0$?

Answer (score 1):

As noticed, recall that by standard limit

- $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}= 1$

or by definition of derivative with $f(x)=e^x$

- $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f(0)=1$

therefore

$$\frac{e^x-1}{x^2}=\frac1x \cdot\frac{e^x-1}{x}\to\pm \infty$$